# Could I backup mySQL without storing my password at the file?

Tags: backup

I use the following script under `/etc/crontab` to make a daily backup of my MySQL database (up to the last 30 days):

```
0 8 * * * mysqldump -u root -PASSWORD --all-databases > /root/backups/mysql/db.sql
1 8 * * * zip /root/backups/mysql/db-$(date +\%F-\%T-).sql.zip /root/backups/mysql/db.sql
2 8 * * * rm /root/backups/mysql/db.sql
2 8 * * * find /root/backups/mysql/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

I need to type my password where it is written PASSWORD. This is problematic because then my root DB password is exposed if someone hacks the system. Is there a way to make the exact same automatic backups without writing the password exposed?

Comment: If someone successfully hacks the system (gains `root` access), the system, including the database, should be considered lost and be reinstalled anyway.  See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html